# How can I get table cell value as "xyz" WITHOUT hit the Enter or Tab key?

Tags: java, key, tableviewer

I found out if you editing a TableViewer cell without hit the Enter or Tab key. Then the new cell value won't take effect. For example, a table cell value is "abc" and you change it to "xyz". Then when you read that table cell value, it still "abc". You MUST hit the Enter or
Tab key, then you will get that table cell value as "xyz".

How can I force that table cell value as "xyz" WITHOUT hit the Enter or Tab key?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you check the tableviewer api.
if it was a standard JTable you simply use this:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: Losing focus means hitting tab or clicking elsewhere...if this is still not acceptable (I would wonder why) then you need to put a timeout on the editor so that after a certain time without typing the edit is taken into account...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there any solution for TableViewer?

Comment: @Julien Bidault: Can you let me know how to set timeout for celleditor of tableviewer?

Comment: I haven't done Swing in ages, but from my memory : the fact you focus out of the cell, or the fact you press enter trigger en event. The fact your type in the cell trigger an event as well. What you can do is register a listener to the "typing" event, that will launch a timer. If a new key is pressed, the timer is reset to its original value. Once the time reaches 0, you manually trigger an event that validates the content of your cell (there are a lot of event, pick the proper one). The trick will be the management of the timer (only one timer, and handle other type of events)

Comment: not an answer a) TableViewer != JTable b) doesn't help anyway for JTable, as live (on key type) commit is not supported

Comment: i knew it was probably be not the same since there was little explanation it could have been a JTable.

Answer (score 0):

Temporally, i make a losing focus by set focus from current view to another view in RCP :). It's not official solution but effect.